# There is a way to remove all this tag?

Tags: sublimetext2, bbcode

I, I have this tags:

```
[URL="http://www.site1.com/hash"][IMG]http://image1.com/image.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
[URL="http://www.site2.com/hash"][IMG]http://image2.com/image2.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

And so on. This for around 70 images and link. 
Anyway, I made a mistake in this BB-Style formatting. The forum where I would like to post this message doesn't understand the url code. So I get a result llike this:

[url="http://www.site1.com/hash"]*Here appears the image correctly*[/url]

So, there is a way in Sublime text for remove all the 70 tags: 
[url="http://www.site1.com/hash"] by once, if the url change for every code?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want `[URL="http://www.site1.com/hash"][IMG]http://image1.com/image.jpg[/IMG][/URL]` to eventually look like?

Comment: I just want this result: [IMG]http://image1.com/image.jpg[/IMG]... and remove this: [URL="http://www.site1.com/hash"][/URL]
Anyway, the link inside change for every line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is select `[URL="http://www.site1.com/hash"]`, then do a regex replace with the pattern `\[URL=.*?\]` and the Replace: field blank.

Once you've done that, do a regex replace with the pattern `(\[/IMG\])\[/URL\]` and put `\1` in the Replace: field.